# Position in recylerview changes while scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Seems like position in recylerview changes while scrolling.

What I want to do is like this.

`Adapter.java`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(aViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        holder.zeroIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        holder.oneIcon.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.otherIcon.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // Set text on each item
    ...
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() { return models.size(); }

public class aViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView zeroIcon;
    private ImageView oneIcon;
    private ImageView otherIcon;


    public aViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        zeroIcon = itemview.findViewById(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

I set these icon's visibility `GONE` as default in `xml` file.

When I see the recylerview at first, the icons show up as I expected depending on its position.

However, when I scroll down and scroll up, incorrect icons also show up on incorrect position.
Like `otherIcon` shows up on the first and second item while scrolling down and up. While scrolling down, `zeroIcon` and `oneIcon` show up on some other items.

How can I fix this?

`list_item.xml` is like this.

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/zero"
         android:visiblity="gone"
         android:background="@drawable/zero" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@id/one"
         android:visiblity="gone"
         android:background="@drawable/one" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@id/other"
         android:visiblity="gone"
         android:background="@drawable/other" />
```

Comment: can you share xml of your recycler item

Comment: try to share full code of adapter and don't put ... maybe bug is where you don't think at all

Comment: Well, It happens in `ListView` and `RecyclerView` both. You need to set initial variables in case there is no value.

Comment: Android recyclerview uses cell repeatedly means if you scroll down then 1st position memory will be reused for another item, so this is causing issue with you. Add **holder.oneIcon.setVisiblity(View.GONE);** and **holder.otherIcon.setVisiblity(View.GONE);**  in first if condition of bindview and follow same for others.   This will definitely help you.

Comment: do add onItemChanged after setting visibility

Comment: @tejraj Thanks this explanation helped me to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modify it in this way,

```
if (position == 0) {
    holder.zeroIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.otherIcon.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
    holder.oneIcon.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
} else if (position == 1) {
    holder.oneIcon.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.zeroIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.otherIcon.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
} else {
    holder.otherIcon.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.oneIcon.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
    holder.zeroIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

In `RecyclerView` you should manage other views also while changing an item.